# How to fill only a part of the SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, svg

I want to be able to pass a number/percentage to a function that fills a part of an svg. For example in an svg of a bucket if the real life bucket is filled 90% of the way and it returns 10 liters as an integer I want the bucket svg on my website to be filled 90% of the way with blue.

I believe you can portion an SVG into parts with an ID and fill each ID based on the number the function is passed and then edit each part with some kind of jquery function? However, I feel like filling only part of an SVG must be a more popular thing to do but I haven't been able to find a straightforward/simple way of doing this?

Comment: You can do this with a linearGradient with two stops to create a hard boundary. The stops would be at the percentage fill point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with a `<linearGradient>`.

```js
function setWaterLevel(percent)
{
  document.getElementById("stop1").setAttribute("offset", percent+"%");
  document.getElementById("stop2").setAttribute("offset", percent+"%");
}


document.getElementById("slider").addEventListener("input", function(evt) {
  setWaterLevel(evt.target.value);
});

setWaterLevel(0);
```

```html
<svg width="300px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="water" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
      <stop id="stop1" offset="0%" stop-color="blue"/>
      <stop id="stop2" offset="0%" stop-color="transparent"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <polygon points="0,0, 100,0, 80,100, 20,100"
           fill="url(#water)" stroke="black"/>
</svg>

<br>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="10" value="0"/>
```

Comment: Thanx. However it seems to me that when your `offsets` are equal to `50%`, you are not filling the `50%` of the water in the glass due to its irregular shape. Is there a way to get a proportional filling of the area?

Comment: @floatingpurr Yes. Don't set the stops to the same percentage as was passed in. Instead, calculate the correct stop percentage appropriate to the shape, and use that instead.  But that calculation is your resposibility to work out.  Their isn't an automatic way, to do that - if that is what you are asking.

Comment: nice comment reminding the single responsibilty principle. Thanx again.

Comment: @floatingpurr I'm not sure I understand your comment. All I meant was that you'll need to work out how to convert the "percentage full" value to a suitable percent for the gradient.  For simple shapes such as this bucket, it wouldn't be so hard to work out (or fake).  But it would get  very hard for some shapes. :-/

Comment: Yes, very neat! Sorry if my comment wasn’t clear. I was pointing out the bottom line of your hint: gradients just manage stop points. Any other processing should be handled apart.

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution is probably going to be to use two `<canvas>` tags and write the fill portion over the container portion. That way you can calculate both separately and don't have to worry about a partial SVG file.

Doing it this way, you'll have much greater control over everything.